# unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, media

I got a theme installed and it works just fine, except when i try to see a product, every time I get this error that you can see here http://bit.ly/2dqrlIh
My knowledge in PHP are minimum and I don't really know what am I looking for in the phtml [file](http://www.sensacionhogar.com/downloads/media.phtml)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: please post the code of your phtml file

Comment: it is too long so I posted a link to the download

Comment: If you rename the file`http://www.sensacionhogar.com/downloads/media.phtml` to `http://www.sensacionhogar.com/downloads/media.phtml.txt` we should be able to fix the error.

Comment: done that is a copy of the original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no closing brace for the if-statement on line 81: `if($total_images > 0) {`
This should probably be inserted after line 95: `<?php } ?>`

Comment: you my friend, you are boss. I broke my head adding and removing code all over the file and couln't figure out. Thanks a freaking lot.